# How to replace node modules folder on a different computer?

Tags: ionic-framework

I could not use `git push` for my ionic app due to the `node modules` folder being too long.

I used `.gitignore` to ignore the `node_modules`, `platforms` and the `plugins` folder as a solution.

My comp broke and now I have a loaner comp that I'd like to continue developing on.

When I git pull from this new computer, I know how to add back the `platforms` and `plugins` with command line tools, but I'm at a loss on how to add the `node modules` folder.

I saved app in a zip before my comp broke, but I can't even unzip this in my new comp because the `node modules` folder is too long when unzipping...

How do I get back the `node modules` folder into this cloned directory? (Side question, can I just copy the `platforms` and `plugins` folder from my zip into this cloned folder, or do I need to use command line tools with `ionic platforms add ...` and `ionic plugin add ...`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to open the command line and navigate to the project folder. Then you can run the following command to redownload the node packages. The node_modules folder is only necessary if you use the gulp tasks (such as sass).

```
npm install
```

The other two commands, `ionic platforms add [platform]` and `ionic plugin add [plugin]` setup the project for a particular platform and plugin. You can copy these two folders back in. When you create a platform, such as ios, you generate a set of files that you may modify for deployment. You'll want to retain the changes to the project configuration, so I would keep them in your git repository.

Comment: Thanks this worked and thanks for explaining to me what is happening with the platforms and plugin folders!